# [CICD]Cloud Build and Cloud Run are not connecting

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I built a continuous deployment from Github with Cloud Build, when I push to the master branch, Cloud Build is running.

I linked this to Cloud Run and it worked the first time, but since then, when I push to the master branch of github, the Cloud Build log works fine, but the Cloud Run service is not updated at all.

When I looked at the log of Cloud Run, there is no description of the error that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

How did you set this up? Can you share your redacted config file? Did you follow the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run#continuous_deployment)